# Django form using HTML template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to Django and I have been trying to get this form to POST. I have read the documentation on forms but i'm a bit confused by it as I am not sure how to implement the Jquery date picker or drop down menu if i create a forms.py file.

I have created the template and i can access it and it formats exactly how i want, however I can't workout how to get it to POST. The idea is to take the data in the form and insert it into a Postgres table.

Template submit.py

```
{% extends 'website/header.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <p><b>Submit Job</b></p>
    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <b>Select Asset to transcode</b>
        <p>Material ID:
            <input type="text" name="material_id" size="30" value="" id="keyword"/>
        </p>
        <p>Profile:
            <select name="workflow">
                <option value="">Select a transcode Profile</option>
                {%  for i in object_list %}
                    <option value="{{ i.name }}">{{ i.name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </p>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#start_datepicker" ).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
                });
            });
        </script>
        <p>License Start Date: <input type="text" id="start_datepicker" name="start_date"></p>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#end_datepicker" ).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
                });
            });
        </script>
        <p>License End Date: <input type="text" id="end_datepicker" name="end_date"></p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        material_id = request.POST['material_id']
        workflow = request.POST['workflow']
        start_date = request.POST['start_date']
        end_date = request.POST['end_date']
        return render(request, 'submit/submit.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'submit/submit.html')
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /submit/
[08/Feb/2017 17:28:49] "POST /submit/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

EDIT

Here are the URL files:

mysite url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('website.urls')),
    url(r'^submit/', include('submit.urls')),
    url(r'^repo/', include('asset_db.urls')),
]
```

submit url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import ListView
from asset_db.models import Profiles

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Profiles.objects.all().order_by("id"), template_name='submit/submit.html')),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using ListView for this url. But ListView allowed only GET request. That's why when it get request with POST method. It is giving error METHOD NOT ALLOWED. 
Create a view for this url in your views.py and define get and post method.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it really helped me understand what i needed to do!

Answer (score 2):

Check that your urls.py file has something like

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^submit/$', 'yourapp.views.submit'),
)
```

datepicker is not related to the issue. Most likely you post to another view. Check all urls and view names.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a view mapped to your submit URL. Your only URL under /submit is a ListView.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested creating a view and not using ListView fixed the issue.

Updated submit views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from asset_db.models import Profiles


def submit(request):
    profiles = Profiles.objects.order_by('-id')
    context = {'profiles': profiles}
    return render(request, 'submit/submit.html', context)


def success(request):
    profiles = Profiles.objects.order_by('-id')
    context = {'profiles': profiles}
    return render(request, 'submit/success.html', context)
```

Updated template submit.html

```
{% extends 'website/header.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <p><b>Submit Job</b></p>
    <form action="{% url 'success' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <b>Select Asset to transcode</b>
        <p>Material ID:
            <input type="text" name="material_id" size="30" value="" id="keyword"/>
        </p>
        <p>Profile:
            <select name="workflow">
                <option value="">Select a transcode Profile</option>
                {%  for i in profiles %}
                    <option value="{{ i.name }}">{{ i.name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </p>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#start_datepicker" ).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
                });
            });
        </script>
        <p>License Start Date: <input type="text" id="start_datepicker" name="start_date"></p>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#end_datepicker" ).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
                });
            });
        </script>
        <p>License End Date: <input type="text" id="end_datepicker" name="end_date"></p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Webserver results:

```
[09/Feb/2017 08:55:22] "GET /submit/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3300
[09/Feb/2017 08:55:29] "POST /submit/success/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2043
```

I used [Django Tutorial part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render) for help with creating the context. Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction!