# Use an existing HTML Template Form and submit data through Django

Tags: django

I'd like to make a `POST REQUEST` with an existing `HTML FORM`, to store it in a database, but everytime I tried to submit data through the form, it doesn't do nothing. it doesn't add data to the database. What should I do?

By the way I'm doing this following those post:

[Django form using HTML template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120060/django-form-using-html-template)

[MultiValueDictKeyError generated in Django after POST request on login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736141/multivaluedictkeyerror-generated-in-django-after-post-request-on-login-page)

**Registro.html**

```
{% extends "RegistrarProyecto/layout.html" %}


{% block title %} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Crear Usuario</h1> 

<form class="CrearUsuario" action="{% url 'registro' %}" method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text",name="NombreProyecto", placeholder="Nombre del Proyecto" >
    <br> 
    <br> 
    <input type ="text", name="ResponsableProyecto", placeholder ="Responsable del proyecto">
    <br> 
    <br> 
    <textarea name="DescripcionProyecto", rows="4", cols="50"></textarea>
    <br> 
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Registrar">
    </form>
<br>
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Ir a Bienvenido</a>

{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def registro(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        NombreProyecto = request.POST.get('NombreProyecto')
        ResponsableProyecto = request.POST.get('ResponsableProyecto')
        DescripcionProyecto = request.POST.get('DescripcionProyecto')
        return render(request, 'RegistrarProyecto/Registro.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'RegistrarProyecto/Registro.html')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Proyecto(models.Model):
    NombreProyecto = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
    ResponsableProyecto = models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    DescripcionProyecto = models.CharField(max_length = 64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.NombreProyecto}"
    
class Evaluador(models.Model):
    NombreEvaluador = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    Proyecto = models.ManyToManyField(Proyecto, blank=True, related_name="Evaluador")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.NombreEvaluador} {self.Proyecto}"
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("Registro", views.registro, name="registro")

]
```

**UPDATE N°1**

[image]

After applying the changes I recibe the following error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def registro(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':

      NombreProyecto = request.POST.get('NombreProyecto')
      ResponsableProyecto = request.POST.get('ResponsableProyecto')
      DescripcionProyecto = request.POST.get('DescripcionProyecto')

      Proyecto.objects.create(NombreProyecto=NombreProyecto,ResponsableProyecto=ResponsableProyecto,DescripcionProyecto=DescripcionProyecto)
      return redirect("to_some_url_name") 
        

  return render(request, 'RegistrarProyecto/Registro.html')
```

**Update**

replace this line

```
<input type="text",name="NombreProyecto", placeholder="Nombre del Proyecto" >
```

with this:

```
<input type="text", name="NombreProyecto", placeholder="Nombre del Proyecto">
```

apperantly the space between name and comma, caused it to return None

Comment: Thanks  ! but after the changes I recibe an integrity error, I don't understand what it means (Updated post above)

Comment: i updated the answer, it was the html file that caused the problem, now it should work